# Parse list of Short URL's

Tags: parsing, url

I have a nice long list of shortened URLs with identifiers, like:

43242     http://t.co/12352

61431     http://t.co/16192

98718     http://t.co/95351
.

Wondering if a utility exists to feed a list of shortened links and have it return the long version?

Answer (score 0):

The full url is available as an entity.

You can get this with the streaming API.

Here is an example for you : [Twitter Full URL - Shortened URL](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3719)